# No error message when email account exists while checking out as new customer

Tags: checkout, magento-enterprise, onepage-checkout

Recently we've gotten quite a few complaints from long-time customers who haven't purchased anything in a while.

They'll add items to their cart then check out as a new customer instead of logging in.

The problem is that the one page checkout billing page is not displaying an error message stating that the account exists (ideally with a forgot password link). The page simply doesn't move forward (it also resets the state field).

I'm not seeing any JavaScript or PHP errors and the developer I'd typically turn to for issues with checkout is booked pretty solid.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

I'm running a fully patched Magento EE ver. 1.12.0.2

Comment: Do you have access to your Apache logs? You'll maybe find something useful there.

Comment: I apologize to everyone that answered. I stopped looking after I didn't have any answers after a few days and for some reason I didn't egt the notification. Yes, I checked the Apache logs. Nothing seems to be throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix until your developer is back:

1. Disable guest checkout at **System > configuration > checkout > enable guest checkout**. once disabled if customer tries to register with an already existing email Magento will show popup: [image]

it is hard to say exactly what the problem is not being able to look at the code. to me it looks like some 3rd party extension comes into play. default Magento will let checkout with an existing email no problem.

Comment: Thanks. I think you may have misunderstood a bit. You can checkout with an existing email. The problem is that an error isn't thrown if a user that already has an account try's to create a new account at checkout. It should throw an error "An account with this email already exists".